# java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, driver, appium, verifyerror

I'm having an issue with this appium driver i'm running with java. I'm not exactly sure what I did that caused this error. I was reorganizing my jar files an re configured them. However that shouldn't be what was causing it. I also tried starting appium programatically. but that deem unsuccessful. So I deleted that code and started getting this error. It stops right on this code "driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumURL, capabilities);" after initiating driver capabilities and URL. It use to work, and now it doesn't and I don't know exactly what this error is referring to. I need help. I looked up other answers, but all they're saying is that a super class can't refer to another super class or something like that. But I just don't understand what that means and how that relates to this.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.<init>(JsonHttpCommandCodec.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:85)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:43)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:55)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:97)
    at Test_Login.setup(Test_Login.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test_Login.cleanUp(Test_Login.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html), "a class that is declared final cannot be subclassed."

Comment: @Michael It's not as simple as that. If it were, you'd get a javac error and not a link error, as here. It's that the Selenium libraries got upgraded and it seems there's some binary-incompatible changes in the upgrade, where the old version had a final class that became un-final in the newer version (or vice versa).

Comment: Usually something like this indicates mismatched versions of libraries in your class path.  (Version A of library A is expecting Version Y of library Y, but your classpath has Version X or Z of library Y)

Comment: @AndrewParra Contrary to your expectations, your reorganisation of your jars probably _was_ what caused the issues. ;-) The stack trace helped me see that Selenium's `JsonHttpCommandCodec` was trying to load a class that failed to load; in the current version of `JsonHttpCommandCodec`, [on line 64](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/JsonHttpCommandCodec.java#L64), it's trying to load `JsonToBeanConverter`, which isn't final. So I have  nothing further to go on, unless you know which version of Selenium is being used.

Comment: @AndrewParra It would also be good to see the code used by you before the driver initialisation including the capabilities set.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I will reorganize the jar files again when I go back to the office. The issue was that I put all the jar files in a "libs" folder, however it got crowded with all the jar's source's and javadoc's that I created a folder for each jar file with its respected source and javadoc, then reconfigured the jar locations. I'll put them back the way they were. and see where that gets me. :) thanks!

Comment: @nullpointer Once I get my hands on the code I'll post it here.