# java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class - Selenium 3.81

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

```
    String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path+"/driver/windowgecko.exe"); 

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0ei=rrJ1WvqJAe_H8gfwi4GQAg");
```

When I run my sample script using selenium 3.8 using the above code I get "java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class "

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the class this above code is in look like?

Comment: There is no other class, I have executed this in a main method.

Comment: Right, but the main method occurs in a class, what's the class definition look like?

Comment: public class test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
  String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path+"/driver/windowgecko.exe"); 
  WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=rrJ1WvqJAe_H8gfwi4GQAg");


}
}

Comment: Ok, so it's not your code based on what you posted.  This same issue was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623965/java-lang-verifyerror-cannot-inherit-from-final-class.  Are you sure that you're compiling your app using the same version of selenium libraries that you're using at run time?  Examine the classpath at compile and runtime.

Comment: Please include additional information by editing your question, not by posting a comment. Especially if it is multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code with the latest maven selenium version, which is selenium 3.8.1

It looks like it is not your code which is producing the error. Maybe check your libraries and dependencies. :)

Comment: could you please confirm the list of libraries that were downloaded for 3.8.1

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.8.1 - got the dependency list from this one. Except for the selenium libs i also get some more from e.g. google gson, etc. the selenium libs should be the same, though. Hope this helps  ^^

Comment: Thanks Last Question. Could you tell me which package/jar this line of code is coming from "WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver()".

Comment: sure, the FirefoxDriver class is from package:

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

and the WebDriver Class is imported from:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver